Does forgetful functor commute with limits?
Let $C$ be a category of rings, groups, modules etc. Let $F:C\rightarrow SETS$ be the forgetful functor taking the underlying set. Does $F$ commute with limits? One need this result to show that a presheaf $\mathcal F$ is a sheaf with values in $C$ if and only if after applying the forgetful functor it is a sheaf of sets, ie. $F(\mathcal F)$ is a sheaf of sets.
Let $L$ be limit in $C$ and let $N$ be a cone in $C$, then we want to verify if there exists a unique morphism $f:N\rightarrow F(L)$ making the diagram commute. But I think in the category of sets there is no reason to believe such $f$ is unique.

I'm not sure if this is this what you are looking for, but if $H$ is the category of Hilbert spaces, then the sequence of spaces $\Bbb{R} \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2 \subseteq \ldots$ has a limit which does not correspond in any natural way with the set-theoretic limit of the underlying sets.

In all of the cases you list $F$ is right adjoint to some functor (free $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra functor, free group functor, free module functor) and therefore preserves limits. There is no reason to expect this for general concrete categories because "concrete category" does not have a concrete definition (as far as I'm aware).

@BenSteffan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category gives what I believe to be the standard definition of a concrete category as a category equipped with a faithful functor to the category of sets. What is wrong with that?

@RobArthan I was (somehow) unaware of that definition. In this case, it's easy to construct lots of counterexamples just by messing around with finite categories.

@BenSteffan: well over to you to post an answer with one of those examples: my Hilbert space example is probably harder for the OP.

@Rob: what morphisms are you using in the category of Hilbert spaces? Are you sure that limit exists in $\text{Hilb}$?

@QiaochuYuan: continous linear transformations. I wouldn't be surprised if I was wrong about this.

@Rob: the category of Hilbert spaces and continuous linear maps doesn't have infinite products. For example the infinite product $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, if it existed, would need to have the property that continuous maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ correspond to $\mathbb{N}$-tuples of continuous maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. This already forces the underlying vector space to be $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, in particular we do not get $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. I'm actually not sure how to finish from here but there's no way this thing can be made into a Hilbert space.

Similarly we should also be able to show that the category of Banach spaces and continuous linear maps doesn't have infinite products. This is why I used $\text{Ban}_1$ in my answer below; the restriction to maps of norm $\le 1$ turns out to be quite natural and the resulting category is complete, cocomplete, closed symmetric monoidal, nearly as nice as you could hope for except that it isn't abelian.

@QiaochuYuan: thanks for your comments. I am sure you are right.

In the strictest sense, there's no reason to expect a forgetful functor $F : C \to \mathsf{Set}$ to preserve limits. This is a ~bonus property~ that you have to explicitly ask for.
However, in lots and lots of situations that arise in practice, the forgetful functor will preserve limits. One crucial example is when your forgetful functor is representable. That is, when there's an object $\star \in C$ so that $F(X) \cong \text{Hom}_C(\star,X)$ naturally in $X$.
For instance, the forgetful functor from the category of topological spaces preserves limits, since $F(X) \cong \text{Hom}(1,X)$ where $1$ is the space with a single point and the only topology you can put on it (do you see why?). Similarly, the forgetful functor from vector spaces (over $k$) preserves limits, since then $F(V) \cong \text{Hom}(k^1,V)$ where $k^1$ is the one dimensional vector space over $k$.
It's a useful fact that representable functors always preserve limits, and since there's usually an object representing the forgetful functor, this does the job.
In your question, you say "let $C$ be a category of rings, groups, modules etc". With this in mind, I'll mention that for every algebraic theory the forgetful functor is representable.  More generally, this is true for essentially algebraic theories (which allow certain partial operations). This is because (essentially) algebraic theories always admit free objects. The free functor is left adjoint to the forgetful functor, which tells us that
$$
\text{Hom}_C(\text{free}(A), X) \cong \text{Hom}_\mathsf{Set}(A, \text{forget}(X))
$$
In particular, since in $\mathsf{Set}$ we know that $\text{forget}(X) \cong \text{Hom}_\mathsf{Set}(1, \text{forget}(X))$, where $1$ is any set with a single element, this tells us that whenever our forgetful functor has a left adjoint we must have
$$
\text{Hom}_C(\text{free}(1),X) \cong 
\text{Hom}_\mathsf{Set}(1, \text{forget}(X)) \cong
\text{forget}(X)
$$
so that $\star = \text{free}(1)$ represents the forgetful functor!
Putting the pieces together, we see that for any "algebraic theory" (like the "groups, rings, modules, etc." that you mentioned) the forgetful functor will have a left adjoint, and thus will preserve limits.

I hope this helps ^_^

The other answers have already addressed the case of models of an algebraic theory which covers groups, rings, modules, etc. This is already enough for sheaf theory, I think. But in any case, here are some examples of what happens more generally, which are reasonably "natural." Below if I haven't specified what the forgetful functor $U$ is then it's the "obvious" one.

Let $C = \text{FinGrp}$ be the category of finite groups. $U$ is not representable and does not have a left adjoint. However, finite limits in $C$ exist and are computed as in $\text{Grp}$, so in this case we can reduce to $\text{Grp}$ and $U$ still preserves finite limits.

Let $C = \text{TorAb}$ be the category of torsion abelian groups. $U$ is not representable and does not have a left adjoint. In this case $U$ does not preserve limits; the infinite product $\prod_i A_i$ in this category is given by the torsion subgroup of the ordinary product, so for example $U$ does not preserve the infinite product $\prod_n \mathbb{Z}/n$.

Let $C = \text{Ban}_1$ be the category of (complex) Banach spaces and short maps (linear maps of norm $\le 1$). $U$ is not representable and does not have a left adjoint. In this case $U$ again does not preserve infinite products; for example the infinite product $\prod_X \mathbb{C}$ turns out to be $\ell^{\infty}(X)$. However, this can be fixed by choosing a different forgetful functor; if we just pick the functor $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{C}, -)$, which sends a Banach space to its unit ball, it's representable so it preserve limits. See e.g. this blog post for more details, especially on why the morphisms are taken to be short maps. If the morphisms are just taken to be continuous / bounded maps I do not believe the resulting category has infinite products.

Let $C = \text{Sch}$ be the category of schemes. If we take "underlying set" to mean the underlying set of points of the corresponding locally ringed space, then $U$ does not even preserve finite limits, and not even finite products; see fiber product of schemes for details. Explicitly it does not even preserve the finite product $\text{Spec } \mathbb{F}_2 \times \text{Spec } \mathbb{F}_3$, which is empty. However, in this case you could argue that $U$ does not deserve to be called the underlying set functor; it's not very well-behaved in many ways (as we're seeing), and it isn't even faithful.



Does the inclusion $\mathrm{FinGrp} \to \mathrm{Grp}$ preserve limits? Is this an instance of a more general fact?

@Naïm: whoops, sorry, I meant to say finite limits. Of course we don't have infinite limits (e.g. we don't have infinite products). The inclusion preserves and reflects finite limits; we just need to observe that 1) finite products of finite groups are finite, 2) the equalizer of a pair of morphisms between two finite groups is finite, and 3) a morphism from an arbitrary group $G$ to a finite collection of finite groups factors through a finite quotient.

I see, so you might say that the inclusion creates finite limits or something.

In the case that $\mathcal{C} \in \{\mathrm{CRing}, \mathrm{Grp}, \mathrm{Mod}_R, \mathrm{Top}\}$ ($R$ some commutative ring) and many more this property holds: In each of these cases, $F$ is right adjoint to some free functor, namely the functor sending a set $S$ to the free $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra/group/$R$-module/discrete topological space on $S$, in order. You then only have to observe that right adjoints preserve limits.
However, if $\mathcal{C}$ is some random concrete category (i.e. a category with a faithful functor $F\colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Set}$), there is no reason to expect that $F$ preserve limits. One can build easy counterexamples just by playing with finite categories; for instance take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the "commutative square" category
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>f_{ab}>> B \\
    @Vf_{ac}VV @VVf_{bd}V\\
    C @>>f_{cd}> D
\end{CD}
where $f_{bd} \circ f_{ab} = f_{cd} \circ f_{ac}$. A functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Set}$ is automatically faithful (after all, all hom-sets in $\mathcal{C}$ are either singletons or empty), and the datum of such a functor is a commutative square in $\mathrm{Set}$, but the limit of $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{C}}\colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ is $A$, so if $F$ preserves limits then its image must be a pullback square, and any non-pullback square in $\mathrm{Set}$ serves as a counterexample.

@chi Thank you, good point! I'll edit it in.
